# Google charts add tooltip

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I would like to add some data on tooltips in my chart but I can't find a way to do it. I tried to add role: tooltip but it didn't work

this is my code:

```
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var cont = 1;
    var rowtbl = document.getElementById("tabella").rows.length;
    rowtbl = rowtbl - 1;

    // use object notation for column headings
    var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      [{type: 'string', label: ''},  {type: 'number', label: 'Tempo in minuti: '}, {type: 'string', role: 'tooltip'}]
    ]);

    //number rows table
    while(cont <= rowtbl){
      var nomi;
      var qnt;
      var time;
      nomi = document.getElementById("tabella").rows[cont].cells[0].innerHTML;
      time = document.getElementById("tabella").rows[cont].cells[3].innerHTML;
      qnt = document.getElementById("tabella").rows[cont].cells[1].innerHTML;

      var info = {
        name: nomi,
        tempo: time,
        qn: qnt,
      };

      // add row to google data
      data.addRow([
        info.name,
        parseFloat(info.tempo),
        info.qn

      ]);

      cont = cont +1;
    }

    var options = {
        tooltip: {isHtml: true},
      legend: { position: 'none' },
      bar: { groupWidth: "80%" }
    };

    var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('top_x_div'));
    chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));
  },
  packages: ['bar']
});
```

I want `qnt = document.getElementById("tabella").rows[cont].cells[1].innerHTML;` to be show in the tooltip.
How do I need to change my code?

Thank you very much guys!

EDIT

I would like my tooltip to look like this, is this possible?[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

need to change column defintion to allow html

from: `{type: 'string', role: 'tooltip'}`

to: `{type: 'string', role: 'tooltip', p: {html: true}}`

**EDIT**

[Columns Roles](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/roles) such as `'tooltip'` and `'style'` do not work on *Material* charts.

you can use a *Core* chart, with the option -- `theme = 'material'` -- to get the look and feel close

the following snippet draws both charts, the tooltips work on the bottom, *Core* chart

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var cont = 1;
    var rowtbl = document.getElementById("tabella").rows.length;
    rowtbl = rowtbl - 1;

    var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      [{type: 'string', label: ''},  {type: 'number', label: 'Tempo in minuti: '}, {type: 'string', role: 'tooltip', p: {html: true}}]
    ]);

    //number rows table
    while(cont <= rowtbl){
      var nomi;
      var qnt;
      var time;
      nomi = document.getElementById("tabella").rows[cont].cells[0].innerHTML;
      time = document.getElementById("tabella").rows[cont].cells[3].innerHTML;
      qnt = document.getElementById("tabella").rows[cont].cells[1].innerHTML;

      var tooltip;
      tooltip =  '<div class="ggl-tooltip">';
      tooltip += '<div><span class="ggl-tooltip-title">' + nomi + '</span></div>';
      tooltip += '<div><span class="ggl-tooltip-category">Tempo in minuti:</span></div>';
      tooltip += '<div><span class="ggl-tooltip-time">' + time + '</span></div>';
      tooltip += '<div><span class="ggl-tooltip-note">' + qnt + '</span></div>';
      tooltip += '</div>';

      data.addRow([
        nomi,
        parseFloat(time),
        tooltip
      ]);

      cont = cont +1;
    }

    var options = {
      bar: {groupWidth: '80%'},
      chartArea: {width: '90%'},
      height: 400,
      legend: {position: 'none'},
      theme: 'material',
      tooltip: {isHtml: true},
      width: '100%'
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('top_x_div_core'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  },
  packages: ['corechart']
});
```

```css
.ggl-tooltip {
  border: 1px solid #E0E0E0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica;
  font-size: 12pt;
  padding: 12px 12px 12px 12px;
}

.ggl-tooltip div {
  padding: 6px 6px 6px 6px;
}

.ggl-tooltip-title {
  color: #000000;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.ggl-tooltip-category {
  color: #676767;
}

.ggl-tooltip-time {
  color: #1565C0;
  font-size: 20pt;
}

.ggl-tooltip-note {
  color: #F44336;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<table id="tabella">
  <tr>
    <th>
      nomi
    </th>
    <th>
      qnt
    </th>
    <th>
    </th>
    <th>
      time
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      utente
    </td>
    <td>
      Here value of qnt
    </td>
    <td>
    </td>
    <td>
      40
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      nomi 2
    </td>
    <td>
      tooltip for nomi 2
    </td>
    <td>
    </td>
    <td>
      2
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      nomi 3
    </td>
    <td>
      tooltip for nomi 3
    </td>
    <td>
    </td>
    <td>
      3
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<div id="top_x_div_core"></div>
```

Comment: I added that but now I dont know how can I show a variable or a text in the tooltip

Comment: yes qnt contain the right value but how can I add it in the tooltip bc right now only time and nomi are showing in the tooltip? Thanks for helping

Comment: see edit to answer above, forgot that columns roles don't work on _Material_ charts...

Comment: I edited my question so you can see how I would like to style my tooltip